# Angular filter maximum decimals

Tags: angularjs, decimal, angularjs-filter, decimal-point

I want to create a new filter such that i get an input, and i give the amount of **maximum** decimals to show and return a string that is formatted according to locale.

```
Input(number)    Output for 1 decimal    Output for 2 decimals
1.01             1                       1.01 / 1,01
1.001            1                       1
1.1              1.1 / 1,1               1.1 / 1,1
1                1                       1
1000             1 000 / 1.000 / 1,000   1 000 / 1.000 / 1,000
```

I want to use angular's built in number filter for locale purposes, but i can't come up with how to remove decimals since if i do it after number filter, then i have a locale specific string, and i cant do it before, since i don't know how to round before i have used `number:x`

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: what does `remove decimals` mean? In the view ... or in the model?

Comment: The view, I want the filter to return a string, just as angulars own number filter

Comment: so when `x` is a scope variable what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added my own filter, implemented as such:

```
app.filter('numberNoDecimalsIfZeroFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(value, fractionSize) {
        //If has  no decimals, then don't show
        if(value%1 === 0){
            fractionSize = 0;
        }
        return $filter('number')(value,fractionSize);
    }
});
```

Used as such:

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Amount: </label>
      {{::value.amount | numberNoDecimalsIfZeroFilter}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Usage is exactly like angulars "number" filter

Answer (score 1):

You can't, see filter's implementation:

```
// format fraction part.
while (fraction.length < fractionSize) {
  fraction += '0';
}
```

The filter always adds zeros. If you want to achieve what you want, you have to write your own filter.